# React Native FlatList scrollToBottom not working

Tags: android, react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

Greeting everyone,

I am working on react-native `FlatList` and my problem is that I am unable to scroll to bottom. Here is my `FlatList` code:

```
<FlatList style = { styles.list }
  ref="flatList1"
  data = {
    this.state.conversation_arr
  }
  onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
    this.flat_list_height = contentHeight;
    // this.scrollNow();
  }}
  onLayout={this.scrollNow()}
  renderItem = { this._renderItem }
  keyExtractor = { item => item.message_id }
/>

scrollNow() {
  console.log("******",this.refs);
  if(this.refs.flatList1){
    this.refs.flatList1.scrollToEnd();
  }
}
```

When the code reaches to

```
this.refs.flatList1.scrollToEnd();
```

Error appears on the screen saying

```
Type Error, cannot read property -1 of undefined.
```

here is the screenshot.

[cannot read property -1 of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnD24.png)
I am basically trying to implement chat feature for my application, and therefor i need to scroll to bottom of the list once chat is loaded.

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    ActivityIndicator,
    TouchableOpacity,
    FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Conversation extends Component {

state = {
    conversation_arr: undefined,
    last_message_loaded: false,
    show_activty_indicator: true,
    message_text : undefined,
    message_text_length : 0
};


params = this.props.navigation.state;

last_evaluated_key = {
    message_id: undefined,
    timestamp: undefined
}
conversation = undefined;
thread_info = undefined;
flat_list_height = 0;


static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.header_title,
});

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._renderItem = this._renderItem.bind(this);
    this._fetchConversation();
    this.scrollNow = this.scrollNow.bind(this);
    this.handleInputTextContent = this.handleInputTextContent.bind(this);
    this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);

    console.disableYellowBox = true;

    this.thread_info = this.params.params.thread_info;
}

// scrollNow() {
    // console.log("******",this.refs);
    // if(this.refs.flatList1){
    //     // debugger;
    //     this.refs.flatList1.scrollToEnd();
    // }

    // console.log("******", this.flatlist1);
    // if(this.flatlist1){
    //     this.flatlist1.scrollToEnd();
    // }
    // console.log("###", this.flat_list_height);
// }
scrollNow = () => {
    console.log("******", this.flatList1);
    if(this.state.conversation_arr && this.state.conversation_arr.length > 0 && this.flatList1){
        // debugger;

        // setTimeout(() => {
            // console.log("timer over now");
            this.flatList1.scrollToEnd();
        // }, 1000)

        // this.flatList1.scrollToEnd();
        console.log("Scrolling now at length", this.state.conversation_arr.length);

    }



    // !!this.refs["myFlatList"] && this.refs["myFlatList"].scrollToEnd()

}

componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log("componentDidUpdatecomponentDidUpdate")
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log("componentWillUnmountv")
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            {   
                this.state.show_activty_indicator &&
                <View style={[styles.activity_indicator_container]}>
                    <ActivityIndicator
                        animating = { this.state.show_activty_indicator }
                        size="large"
                        color="#444444" 
                    />
                </View>
            }
            <FlatList style = { styles.list }
                // inverted
                // ref="myFlatList"
                // ref={(ref) => this.flatList1 = ref}
                ref={(ref) => { this.flatList1 = ref; }}
                data = {
                    this.state.conversation_arr
                }
                onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
                    this.flat_list_height = contentHeight;
                    // this.scrollNow();
                }}
                onLayout={this.scrollNow}
                renderItem = { this._renderItem }
                keyExtractor = { item => item.message_id }
            />

            <View style={ styles.bottom_box }>
                <Text style={ styles.message_length }> {this.state.message_text_length}/160 </Text>
                <View style={ styles.message_box }>
                    <View style={{flex: 3}} >
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.input_text}
                            value={this.state.message_text}
                            onChangeText={this.handleInputTextContent}
                            placeholder='Type a message here...'
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1}} >
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.send_button} 
                            onPress={this.sendMessage} >
                                <Text style={[styles.label_send]}>SEND</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );

}

handleInputTextContent(text){

    if(text.length > 160){
        text = text.substring(0,159)
        this.setState({ message_text : text });
    } else {
        this.setState({ message_text : text });
        this.setState({ message_text_length : text.length });
    }
}

sendMessage(){
    console.log(this.state.message_text);
    if(this.state.message_text && this.state.message_text.length > 0) {
       console.log("Send message now");
    }
}

_renderItem(item, index){
    // console.log(item.item);
    item = item.item;

    let view = (
            <Text style = { [styles.msg_common] }> { item.message_content } </Text>
        )

    return   view ;
}

processPaymentMessages(dataArr) {
    return dataArr;
}

_fetchConversation() {

            new WebApi().fetchThreadConversation().then(result => {
                console.log("resutlresult", result);

                if (result && result.data && result.data.LastEvaluatedKey) {

                    this.last_evaluated_key.message_id = result.data.LastEvaluatedKey.message_id;
                    this.last_evaluated_key.timestamp = result.data.LastEvaluatedKey.timestamp;

                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        last_message_loaded: true
                    });
                    this.last_evaluated_key = null;
                }

                if (!this.conversation) {
                    this.conversation = [];
                }


                for (let i = 0; i < result.data.Items.length; i++) {

                        item = result.data.Items[i];
                        this.conversation.push(item);
                }

                // console.log(this.conversation);
                this.setState({ conversation_arr : this.conversation });
                this.setState({ show_activty_indicator : false });

                console.log(this.state.conversation_arr.length);


            }, error => {
                console.log("web api fetch data error", error);
            })
    }
}
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        activity_indicator_container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 8,
    backgroundColor:"#fff"
},

list : {
    paddingLeft: 8,
    paddingRight:8,
    marginBottom : 85,
},

gray_item: {
    padding: 10,
    height: 44,
    backgroundColor:"#fff"
},
white_item : {
    padding: 10,
    height: 44,
    backgroundColor:"#f5f5f5"
},

msg_common : {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
},
colored_item_common : {
    padding : 12,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'

}, 
item_insider_common : {
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    fontSize : 16,
    padding : 12,
    borderWidth : 1,
    borderRadius : 8,
    width : "90%",
    fontWeight : "bold",
    textAlign: 'center',

},
purple_item_insider : {
    color : "#7986cb",
    borderColor: "#7986cb",

}, 
green_item_insider : {
    color : "#66bb6a",
    borderColor: "#66bb6a",

},

bottom_box:{
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    flex: 1,
},
message_length: {
    height : 20,
    textAlign: 'right', alignSelf: 'stretch'
},
message_box: {
    // position: 'absolute',
    // left: 0,
    // right: 0,
    // bottom: 0,
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: "row"
},

input_text: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 60,
    color: '#000',
    backgroundColor:"#eee",
    padding: 16,
},
send_button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1, 
    height: 60,
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor : '#f1592b'
},
label_send: {
    color: '#fff'
}
  })
```

Comment: `ref="flatList1"` has been deprecated.  You should use a function to get the ref, i.e.  `ref={(ref) => this.flatList1 = ref}`

Comment: @Johan i tried this approach but now the error is  `cannot read property "scrollToEnd" of undefined`

Comment: If you use the function, then you need to use `this.flatlist1.scrollToEnd()` and not `this.refs.flatlist1.scrollToEnd()`

Comment: still the same :/ `this.flatlist1` is undefined

Comment: If it's a chat app, it should be easier to track # of messages. Have you considered `scrollToIndex({ index: index, animated: true, viewPosition: 1})`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a callback to onLayout like this:

```
onLayout={this.scrollNow}
```

The updated code is: I tried it. It works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        ref={(ref) => { this.flatList1 = ref; }}
        data={[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
        onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => { this.flat_list_height = contentHeight; }}
        onLayout={this.scrollNow}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.message_id}
      />
    );
  }
  renderItem =() => <Text style={{marginTop: 100}}>Just Some Text</Text>
  scrollNow =() => {
    if (this.flatList1) {
      this.flatList1.scrollToEnd();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i still got the same issue, as i mentioned above in my question

Comment: tried your code, now Flatlist scrolls but not to the bottom, it stops at the middle of screen

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing an empty array when "this.state.conversation_arr" is undefined or null. Checking this._renderItem can be helpful also, weather it is trying to access -1 of any argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts wrong in your code.

1. the ref in FlatList is a function, not a string.
2. If you don't use arrow function, the FlatList cannot access the "this" in scrollNow() function.

I tested with similar code. The code below should work.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
export default class Conversation extends React.Component {
  flatList1;
  _interval;
  state = { conversation_arr: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    let buffer = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 40; i++) {
      buffer.push({ message_id: i, message_content: `I'm the message ${i}` });
    }

    this._interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(() => {
        return { conversation_arr: buffer };
      });
      this.flatList1.scrollToIndex({
        index: buffer.length - 1,
        viewPosition: 1,
        viewOffset: 0,
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this._interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          ref={ref => {
            this.flatList1 = ref;
          }}
          data={this.state.conversation_arr}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.message_id}
          getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
            length: 40,
            offset: 40 * index,
            index,
          })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.msg_common}>{item.message_content}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  msg_common: {
    height: 40,
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
});
```

PS: If you have a long list, let's say more than 100. Using onLayout to scroll down might take some time for initial rendering, which provides a really bad user experience. The much better approach may be

1. to reverse the list before rendering
2. provide a sort button and set onRefresh to true during sorting
3. provide a scroll to bottom button list's footer

**Update:**
I noticed the `onContentSizeChange` property is NOT in the documentation.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex
Which version of React-Native are you using?

**Update2:**
The complete code in TypeScript based on yours. I use `setInterval` to simulate the delay from API call.

Any async function should be in `componentDidMount`, because constructor doesn't wait.

`getItemLayout` is used to help FlatList to figure out height. Notice that this is set before the data arrived.

Comment: Thanks @LeekInPajama, i will test your suggested code and will let you know if it works.

Comment: i tried your suggested code but `!!that.refs.flatList1` is false

Comment: Where do you initialize `this.refs` and where do you call `this.scrollNow()` method?  I tested similar code in my FlatList. It seems alright.

Comment: I dont know if `this.refs` needs to be initialised any where other than inside `FlatList` component, and i am also calling `this.scrollNow()` with in `flatlist` i-e `onLayout={this.scrollNow()}`

Comment: i have update my question with my complete code the class in which `FlatList` is created.

Comment: i am using following
`react-native-cli: 2.0.1`
`react-native: 0.51.0`

Comment: I updated my code. It seems your complete code also has some async issue. the scroll function should be called inside the callback function of the async task. Otherwise, the FlatList has no way to know where is the end of the data.

Comment: Thank u so much for your help, i tried this approach too but some of my views are empty now, they don't even appear on the screen they are taking some place in the screen container, but they appear.

Comment: If i could upvote your answer, but i dont have that much reputation. :) GOD bless you.

Comment: It's empty, because of the async setState thing. Do you consider to try a state manager like MobX combines with TypeScript to simplify your code?

Comment: BTW, It's no harm to think about how the app should work, and how does it relate to **React Component Lifecycle**. **1**Render empty list. (App should show something even when is loading.) **2**fetch **3**render received data **4**scroll down to bottom. React doesn't call constructor when re-render. In this case, it doesn't. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor Consider using a state manager such as **MobX**

Comment: Going to try MobX, lets see if it helps :)

Comment: https://github.com/changx03/react-native-mobx-ts-boilerplate I made this bad boy! MobX + React-Native + TypeScript in batch.